# What is the solution for this error: Error - Original error spawn ENOTDIR?

Tags: java, android-studio, appium

Error An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not sign with default certificate. Original error spawn ENOTDIR

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFu6k.png)